# Asp.Net Roles without Roles Provider not working?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, membership

Hallo,
i have created a web site with Asp.Net by using Sql Membership Provider, sitemap and security trimming enabled.
Based on these i have set web.config files into directories for allowing or not the users  access according to their roles.

After some time i removed the MembershipProvider and i creted by hand the "standard" login procedure which cretaed a ticket and a authentication cookie and sets the GenericPrincipal into the Application_AuthenticateRequest.

The problem after these changes is that althought the sitemap displays the right pages for each different user according to his roles, when i click on this page the system redirects me to the "default.aspx" page such as the user is not allowed to enter that page!

**It is strange that the sitemap and security trimming is working BUT actually i cannot enter the pages!!!!!**

Answer (score 0):

You can add users and roles with IIS management tool. This way you can avoid any typing error.